# Error on cron job, but working fine on shell

Tags: shell, cron, mysql, cpanel

I am configuring Cron to backup my sql automatically. However I think that Cron has some issues and it's not working well.

This is the command I am running:

```
mysqldump --opt -Q -uhereisthename -p'hereisthepasswordwithstrangecharactersthatmustbeescaped' databasename | gzip > /home2/username/backups/backupnamefolder/backupdbwebsitename.`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`.gz
```

When I run it via SSH it works fine and generates the backup.
However if I run it via Cron, I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Anybody can suggest what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cron treats % as a special character (meaning "new line", hence the references to lines 0 and 1 in the error message). You need to escape it:

```
date "+\%Y-\%m-\%d"
```

By the way, the posix `$( )` syntax is generally better than backticks - it allows nested commands.

Comment: Hi, the Shell I used is Bash and it works there.
I have done as you said. I cron the command is now `bash -c "mysqldump --opt -Q -uhereisthename -p'hereisthepasswordwithstrangecharactersthatmustbeescaped' databasename | gzip > /home2/username/backups/backupnamefolder/backupdbwebsitename.`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`.gz"` But still I get exactly the same two lines of error starting with `/bin/sh: -c: line`

Comment: Sorry, I realised what was wrong shortly after posting -  see my edited answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have tried both versions. With `(date +"%Y-%m-%d")` and with ``date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d"`` give the same error. :(

Comment: Maybe because I have the % sign in the middle of the password?

Comment: It works! I had to \ escape also the % in the password. I thought the backticks will do it. But they don't. Thank you.